# Qual a curva de performance do arquivo que vai consumir uma XMLHttpRequest via GET segundo o volume de data enviados?

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-request, xmlhttprequest

Gostaria de saber se há um volume de data com melhor performance em uma requisição XMLhttpRequest via GET ou se a performance é sempre diretamente proporcional à quantidade de data

```
 var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', 'arquivo.php?data=muita_data', true);
        request.onload = function() {
         if (this.status >= 200 && this.status < 400) {
        var resp = this.response;
      }
        }
        request.send();
```

Graficamente, minha dúvida é se existe isso, supondo que enviar 3kb seria a melhor situação:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado

Comment: Dados via GET são enviados pela URL e, portanto, seguem as limitações de tamanho da mesma.

Comment: Obrigado, gostaria de ajuda para questões de performance... boa a resposta do 2kb p/ tudo, mas queria entender a curva de desempenho para o tamanho da data; acha melhor mudar a pergunta?

Comment: Sim, principalmente destacando como desejará analisar o desempenho.

Comment: Obrigado, tentei deixar mais claro

Comment: Algo que talvez seja importante para a sua análise: URL é um valor opaco e não *reflete* a aplicação, então, por definição, ela não deveria interferir na performance da mesma.

Comment: Entendi, eu me refiro na questão à performance de consumo do arquivo que será aberto (que vai receber a requisição)... se isso não está claro, provavelmente terei que reformular a pergunta